# Regex split delimiters with content that has no whitespace

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to write a regular expression but I have encountered difficulties.

My goal is to split the contents within 2 delimiters with some conditions.

For example.

```
var str = "foo -word- a b -word2- a b-c -word3- h- b-";
```

The result of the split must be:

```
var result = [
    "foo", "word", "a b",
    "word2", "a b-c",
    "word3", "h- b-"
];
```

For now I have done this:

```
var result = str.split(\-(.*?)-\);
```

But i want to capture only the delimiters that do not contain white space.

Comment: Why does `word` lose hyphens (`-`), but not `h`, or `b`?

Comment: Please state the precise rules you want to follow.

Comment: I want to capture the content in -*- that do not contain whitespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `.*` when you could be specifying a range or class of characters. Try this:

var result = str.split(-(\S+)-);

`\S` is any non-whitespace character, and this is looking for any one or more of them.

Comment: In IE8 and previous i get different results, can you help me?